# Redirecting thread to another function

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, assembly

Here is what I started with, but I am getting an execute violation at some random address from a memory region I cannot view in the disassembly (Not from within the allocated page)

```
// ThreadCallbackParameter = void*
// ThreadCallback = void __stdcall (void*)

// suspend thread
SuspendThread(Thread->Handle);
// get the threads full context
CONTEXT c;
c.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_FULL;
GetThreadContext(Thread->Handle, &c);
// shellcode
// push ThreadCallbackParameter
// call ThreadCallback
// ret
unsigned char shell[] = { 0x68, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xE8, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xC3 };
*(unsigned int*)(shell + 1) = ThreadCallbackParameter;
*(unsigned int*)(shell + 6) = ThreadCallback;
// allocate executable page for shellcode
void* mem = VirtualAlloc(0, sizeof(shell), MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
// copy shellcode to page
memcpy(mem, shell, sizeof(shell));
// redirect thread to shellcode
c.Eip = mem;
SetThreadContext(Thread->Handle, &c);
// resume thread
ResumeThread(Thread->Handle);
return 0;
```

- The page allocated is executable;
- The app is 32-bit, so the assembly
  instructions should be correct;
- The function I wish to call is an
  stdcall so the push should be appropriate;
- I am able to redirect to
  another function trough changing the Eip to the function's address so
  those calls should also be correct (I require shellcode to be able to
  pass arguments to it as well);

Must be some simple code/thinking mistake I am not aware of

Comment: Did you check the return value of `SuspendThread`, `GetThreadContext` and `SetThreadContext` to see if the functions failed or not?

Comment: Is the thread that you are injecting code into in the same process? Or in a different process?

Comment: Does `shellcode` imply "exploit"?

Comment: Yup all of the function calls succeed and the thread that I want to redirect is my own

Comment: @VladFeinstein no, its just the term i picked up. this is for a thread pool project I have (i am aware of all libraries/APIs existing and other challenges that will come up that need fixing)

Comment: Do you get to your `ThreadCallback` or the exception happened before that?

Comment: I have put a breakpoint inside it and it happens after I return from the redirect function but before it reaches the threadcallback function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpCode `0xE8` is the *relative* version of the x86 [`CALL` instruction](https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_26.html).  You are passing it the *absolute* memory address of the callback function you want to jump into, but you need to instead give it a *relative* offset to that function, where that offset is relative to the instruction that *follows* the `CALL` instruction itself.  In this case, you need to take the address of the [`RET` (`0xC3`) instruction](https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_280.html) and subtract that from the address where `ThreadCallback` is pointing to, eg:

```c
PBYTE mem = (PBYTE) VirtualAlloc(0, sizeof(shell), MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
// copy shellcode to page
memcpy(mem, shell, sizeof(shell));
*(PDWORD)(mem + 1) = ThreadCallbackParameter;
*(PINT32)(mem + 6) = ((INT_PTR)ThreadCallback) - ((INT_PTR)(mem + 10));
// redirect thread to shellcode
...
```

---

That being said, you need to call `FlushInstructionCache()` on the allocated memory before executing it.  And you should also remove the `READ/WRITE` flags from the memory as well, to avoid malicious code from hijacking your shell code to do other things.

For better readability, I would also suggest using a `struct` instead of raw bytes for your shell code.

```c
#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct myByteCode
{
    BYTE push;
    DWORD pushValue;
    BYTE call;
    INT32 callOffset;
    BYTE ret;
};
#pragma pack(pop)

// allocate executable page for shellcode
struct myByteCode* mem = (struct myByteCode*) VirtualAlloc(0, sizeof(struct myByteCode), MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);
if (!mem)
{
    // error handling...
}

// copy shellcode to page
mem->push = 0x68;
mem->pushValue = (DWORD) ThreadCallbackParameter;
mem->call = 0xE8;
mem->callOffset = ((INT_PTR)ThreadCallback) - ((INT_PTR)(&mem->ret));
mem->ret = 0xC3;

DWORD ignored;
if (!VirtualProtect(mem, sizeof(struct myByteCode), PAGE_EXECUTE, &ignored))
{
    // error handling...
}

FlushInstructionCache(GetCurrentProcess(), mem, sizeof(struct myByteCode));

// redirect thread to shellcode
...
```

Comment: thanks, the code now works perfectly and i have updated the OP with the working code

Comment: Is calling `FlushInstrunctionCache` worth calling ever? How about in my case where I am writing a mere 11 bytes in a region not previously used?

Comment: @CarolVictor yes, you do need to call `FlushInstructionCache()`, see [If FlushInstructionCache doesn’t do anything, why do you have to call it, revisited](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20190902-00/?p=102828). I have updated my answer to show this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to remy lebeau I have fixed my issue, here is the working version of the code i originally posted:

```
// suspend thread
SuspendThread(Thread->Handle);
// get the threads full context
CONTEXT c;
c.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_FULL;
GetThreadContext(Thread->Handle, &c);
// allocate executable page for shellcode
unsigned char shell[] = { 0x68, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xE8, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xC3 };
void* mem = VirtualAlloc(0, sizeof(shell), MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
// shellcode
// push ThreadCallbackParameter
// call ThreadCallback
// ret
*(unsigned int*)(shell + 1) = ThreadCallbackParameter;
*(unsigned int*)(shell + 6) = (unsigned int)ThreadCallback - (unsigned int)((char*)mem + 10);
// copy shellcode to page
memcpy(mem, shell, sizeof(shell));
// redirect thread to shellcode
c.Eip = mem;
SetThreadContext(Thread->Handle, &c);
// resume thread
ResumeThread(Thread->Handle);
return 0;
```